# Connecting c++ to mysql using mysql-c++-connector 8

Tags: c++, mysql

I want to connect to mysql 8 using mysql-c++-connector8 (xdevapi) and I use .so file for linking but I get errors
here is my **main.cpp** file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>

using namespace ::mysqlx;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main(){

 Session sess("localhost",3306,"root","mypass");
 Schema db = sess.getSchema("university");

 Collection myColl = db.getCollection("student");
 DocResult myDocs = myColl.find("name like :param").execute();

 cout<<myDocs.fetchOne();
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(~/mysql-connector-c++/include)
link_directories(~/mysql-connector-c++/lib64)

set(PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libmysqlcppconn8.so)
add_executable(myExe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myExe ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS})
```

**Errors:**

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable myExe
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `mysqlx::string::string(char const*)':
/home/amir/mysql-connector-c++/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:100: undefined reference to `mysqlx::string::Impl::from_utf8(mysqlx::string&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `mysqlx::string::string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/amir/mysql-connector-c++/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:105: undefined reference to `mysqlx::string::Impl::from_utf8(mysqlx::string&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `mysqlx::string::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >() const':
/home/amir/mysql-connector-c++/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:115: undefined reference to `mysqlx::string::Impl::to_utf8[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::string const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `void mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::set<true, mysqlx::SessionOption, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, mysqlx::SessionOption, unsigned int&, mysqlx::SessionOption, mysqlx::string const&>(mysqlx::SessionOption, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, mysqlx::SessionOption&&, unsigned int&, mysqlx::SessionOption&&, mysqlx::string const&)':
/home/amir/mysql-connector-c++/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/settings.h:67: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::do_set(std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value> > >&&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `void mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::set<true, mysqlx::SessionOption, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(mysqlx::SessionOption, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)':
/home/amir/mysql-connector-c++/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/settings.h:67: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::do_set(std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value> > >&&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `void mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::set<true, mysqlx::SessionOption, mysqlx::string const&>(mysqlx::SessionOption, mysqlx::string const&)':
/home/amir/mysql-connector-c++/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/settings.h:67: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Settings_detail<mysqlx::internal::Settings_traits>::do_set(std::__cxx11::list<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, mysqlx::common::Value> > >&&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/build.make:95: myExe] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/myExe.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: myExe] Error 2
```

I don't want to use legacy connectors as it is not [recommended](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/) .

Comment: What compiler/version are you using? I have no issue with g++ 8.2.0. Your compiler seems to not provide the C++ string ABI from GCC, which is why you get these errors.

Comment: @Holt Aren't these `mysqlx` errors?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I get very very similar error if I set `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` so I am incline to say these are related to the GCC ABI change. Can't say more without knowin the compiler and version used here.

Comment: @Holt: Ah! I see what you're getting at! Yes these seem to be `mysqlx` symbols that relate specifically to strings and it's the swap-out of the string impl that's caused it. Good spot

Comment: @Holt I am using g++ (8.2.1) and clang++ (7.0.1) and getting errors with both of them

Comment: @amir215909 Which version of the connector are using? And on which operating system?

Comment: @amir215909 If you are using g++ 8.2.1, you likely have an "old" version of the connector so maybe try with to add the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`: `add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)`. Note that this may cause issue with other libraries...

Comment: It fixed my problem but I am using the latest connector and according to mysql documentation , (-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0) is not needed                      https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/8.0.html

Comment: @amir215909 Are you using the "Linux - Generic" version of the connectors? I get similar error with these. If you are, you should switch to OS-specific version, if these are available for your OS. I have no issue with the Ubuntu-specific versions.

Comment: @Holt yes I am using "Linux - Generic" version 8 , and my OS is arch linux and it is not available for arch .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR;** You need to use the old GCC ABI by setting the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` to `0`. This can be done with `cmake` by adding the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

---

The issue comes from the "Linux - Generic" of the MySQL connector which have likely been built without the new [CXX11 ABI of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html) (introduced in gcc 5.1).

Since your compiler is recent, the default is to use the new ABI, so when you include `<mysqlx/xdevapi.h>`, you create declarations such as:

```
mysqlx::string::Impl::from_utf8(
    mysqlx::string&, 
    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

...that use the new ABI (see the `__cxx11` namespace).

But since the connectors have been built with the old ABI, the `libmysqlcppconn8.so` contains symbols for functions matching this kind of declaration:

```
mysqlx::string::Impl::from_utf8(
    mysqlx::string&, 
    std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

You can check this by running `readelf -Ws libmysqlcppconn8.so`, for the "Linux - Generic" version I get (with a `grep from_utf8`)<sup>1</sup>:

```
1428: 00000000000a0a86 193 FUNC  GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _ZN6mysqlx6string4Impl9from_utf8ERS0_RKSs
9437: 00000000000a0a86 193 FUNC  GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _ZN6mysqlx6string4Impl9from_utf8ERS0_RKSs
```

But for the Ubuntu 18.10 version I get:

```
  725: 00000000000a23e0 183 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _ZN6mysqlx6string4Impl9from_utf8ERS0_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
10141: 00000000000a23e0 183 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _ZN6mysqlx6string4Impl9from_utf8ERS0_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

The easiest fix is to tell your compiler to use the old ABI, so that the symbol will match. This can be done by setting the `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` macro to 0 when compiling:

```
g++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 main.cpp
```

...or by adding the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
```

If you use multiple external libraries, you have to be careful that those also use the old ABI, otherwise you will likely face the opposite issue, i.e., a library built with the new ABI cannot be used directly to build a program with the old ABI.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The "Linux - Generic" version contains reference to the CXX11 ABI, so I do not really know what is going on here. It looks like some parts of the library has been compile with the new ABI.</sub>

Comment: Since the C++ ABI is a toolchain option, I would sooner add `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT` variable in a toolchain file than use `add_definitions`. Otherwise, this answer is very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to download the specific version for current OS instead generic-linux version.

for example rhel8 x86_64 platform, the **mysql-connector-c++-8.0.23-1.el8.x86_64.rpm** and **mysql-connector-c++-devel-8.0.23-1.el8.x86_64.rpm** should be downloaded. (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/)

Then unarchive that into same folder. (note if you have windows system, please unarchive it in linux since there's some soft link in it)
Then just using it **without** old CXX11ABI (need **NOT** to define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)