# C++ mysqlConnector undefined reference to check

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, visual-studio-2019, mysql-connector

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to program c ++ to a Linux computer. I would like to use the library mysqlConnector for my project. I compansate under

Project properties -> Configuration properties -> VC ++ directories -> Include directories

my path belongs to the folder with the header belonging. In my case this is: /home/system/mysqlConnector/include/jdbc

Then I have under

Project Properties -> Configurations-Properties -> VC ++ Directories -> Library Properties

my path belongs to the .so file. In my case this is: /home/system/mysqlConnector/lib64

In the end I have under

Project Properties -> Configurations-Properties -> Linker -> Settings -> Library Permissions

heard the name of the library. In my case this is mysqlcppconn.

To test that I look at source code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
        try {
        sql::Driver* driver;
        sql::Connection* con;
        sql::Statement* stmt;
        //Create a connection
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://192.168.178.57:3306", "root", "test");
        ///Connect to the MySQL test database
        con->setSchema("test");
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
        sql::ResultSet*  res(stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Test.t"));
        std::cout << "getAnswer" << std::endl;
        while (res->next()) {
           std::cout << res->getString(1) << std::endl;
        }
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;
        
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException& e) {
        std::cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        std::cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line "
            << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        std::cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        std::cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    while (true);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I compile the project now, there are error messages every time:

```
/home/system/projects/mysqlTest1/obj/x64/Debug/main.o: in function `check_lib()': mysqlTest1 D:\usr\bin\ld line 1
```

```
ld returned 1 exit status mysqlTest1 D:\Tamino\Freizeit\Entwicklung\visual Studio\Workspaces\Tests\mysqlTest1\mysqlTest1\collect2 line 1
```

```
undefined reference to `check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' mysqlTest1 D:\home\system\mysqlConnector\include\jdbc\cppconn\driver.h line 77
```

```
/home/system/mysqlConnector/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:78: undefined reference to `check(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)' mysqlTest1 D:\usr\bin\ld line 1
```

Here it is also clearly recognizable that the \home and \usr pathes come from Linux and D: comes from Windows.
Can someone tell me what was I doing wrong?

Comment: Keyword: symbol lookup error: ./demo: undefined symbol: _Z5checkRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

Comment: same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022842/connecting-c-to-mysql-using-mysql-c-connector-8/54040470#54040470