# xdevapi for MySQL using c++ connector linker issues

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11, mysql-x-devapi

I am new and was trying to learn xdevapi for MySQL. i wanted to use it with C++ code on my windows device. but i am having a hard time running sample code. and i am getting a lot of linker errors. there is not much online about these building configuration. and similar queries on internet doesn't have replies.

here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
using namespace mysqlx;

// Scope controls life-time of objects such as session or schema

int main(void) {
  Session mySession("mysqlx://localhost:33060/testdb?user=test&password=test");
  std::list<Schema> schemaList = mySession.getSchemas();

  std::cout << "Available schemas in this session:" << std::endl;

  // Loop over all available schemas and print their name
  for (Schema schema : schemaList) {
    std::cout << schema.getName() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Makefile

```
MYSQL_CONCPP_DIR = C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0
CPPFLAGS = -I "$(MYSQL_CONCPP_DIR)/include" -L "$(MYSQL_CONCPP_DIR)/lib64"
LDLIBS = -lvs14/mysqlcppconn8 -lssleay32 -llibeay32 -lpthread
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g3 -std=c++11
test: test.cpp
```

compiler Output:

```
g++ -Wall -g3 -std=c++11 -I "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include" -L "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64"   test.cpp  -lvs14/mysqlcppconn8 -lssleay32 -llibeay32 -lpthread -o test
In file included from C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:35,
                 from C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/xdevapi.h:91,
                 from test.cpp:3:
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/common.h:60: warning: ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")
 
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::string::string(char const*)':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:110: undefined reference to `mysqlx::string::Impl::from_utf8(mysqlx::string&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::string::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >() const':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:125: undefined reference to `mysqlx::string::Impl::to_utf8[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::string const&)'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::Value::print(std::ostream&) const':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/document.h:506: undefined reference to `mysqlx::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::SessionSettings::SessionSettings(mysqlx::string const&)':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/settings.h:293: undefined reference to `mysqlx::common::Settings_impl::set_from_uri(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Name_src::~Name_src()':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/session.h:271: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Query_src::~Query_src()'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Name_src::~Name_src()':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/session.h:271: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Query_src::~Query_src()'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Schema_src::Schema_src(mysqlx::Session&, mysqlx::string const&)':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/session.h:284: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Name_src::Name_src(mysqlx::Session const&, mysqlx::string const&)'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::~Session_detail()':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/session.h:321: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::close()'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::~Session_detail()':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/detail/session.h:321: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::close()'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::Session::Session(mysqlx::SessionSettings)':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/xdevapi.h:1101: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Session_detail(mysqlx::common::Settings_impl&)'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::internal::Iterator<mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Schema_src, mysqlx::Schema, long long, mysqlx::Schema*, mysqlx::Schema&>::Iterator(mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Schema_src&)':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:335: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Query_src::iterator_next()'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::internal::Iterator<mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Schema_src, mysqlx::Schema, long long, mysqlx::Schema*, mysqlx::Schema&>::operator++()':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:355: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Query_src::iterator_next()'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o: In function `mysqlx::internal::Iterator<mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Schema_src, mysqlx::Schema, long long, mysqlx::Schema*, mysqlx::Schema&>::operator*() const':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:367: undefined reference to `mysqlx::internal::Session_detail::Schema_src::iterator_get()'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTCN6mysqlx5ValueE0_NS_6common5ValueE[_ZTCN6mysqlx5ValueE0_NS_6common5ValueE]+0x20): undefined reference to `mysqlx::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTVN6mysqlx8internal9Query_srcE[.refptr._ZTVN6mysqlx8internal9Query_srcE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::internal::Query_src'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTVN6mysqlx5DbDocE[.refptr._ZTVN6mysqlx5DbDocE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::DbDoc'
C:\Users\sirea\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBh6psQ.o:test.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTVN6mysqlx6common5ValueE[.refptr._ZTVN6mysqlx6common5ValueE]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::common::Value'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: test] Error 1
```

directory tree connector folder

```
Folder PATH listing for volume OS
Volume serial number is 1E28-BDAE
C:.
|   BUILDINFO.txt
|   LICENSE.txt
|   README.txt
|   res
|   
+---include
|   +---jdbc
|   |   |   mysql_connection.h
|   |   |   mysql_driver.h
|   |   |   mysql_error.h
|   |   |   
|   |   \---cppconn
|   |           build_config.h
|   |           config.h
|   |           connection.h
|   |           datatype.h
|   |           driver.h
|   |           exception.h
|   |           metadata.h
|   |           parameter_metadata.h
|   |           prepared_statement.h
|   |           resultset.h
|   |           resultset_metadata.h
|   |           sqlstring.h
|   |           statement.h
|   |           variant.h
|   |           version_info.h
|   |           warning.h
|   |           
|   \---mysqlx
|       |   common.h
|       |   common_constants.h
|       |   xapi.h
|       |   xdevapi.h
|       |   
|       +---common
|       |       api.h
|       |       error.h
|       |       op_if.h
|       |       settings.h
|       |       util.h
|       |       value.h
|       |       
|       \---devapi
|           |   collations.h
|           |   collection_crud.h
|           |   common.h
|           |   crud.h
|           |   document.h
|           |   error.h
|           |   executable.h
|           |   mysql_charsets.h
|           |   mysql_collations.h
|           |   result.h
|           |   row.h
|           |   settings.h
|           |   table_crud.h
|           |   
|           \---detail
|                   crud.h
|                   error.h
|                   result.h
|                   row.h
|                   session.h
|                   settings.h
|                   
\---lib64
    |   libeay32.dll
    |   mysqlcppconn-7-vs14.dll
    |   mysqlcppconn8-1-vs14.dll
    |   ssleay32.dll
    |   
    \---vs14
            libeay32.lib
            mysqlcppconn-static.lib
            mysqlcppconn.lib
            mysqlcppconn8-static.lib
            mysqlcppconn8.lib
            ssleay32.lib
```

i am using 8.12 version

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a visual studio library with gcc

Comment: @AlanBirtles if that so will it not work with gcc?
i don't think they have mentioned it in dev guide as i skimmed through that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022842/connecting-c-to-mysql-using-mysql-c-connector-8
i found this similar query but solution didn't worked for me.

and the query that mod associated with this on closing doesn't help at all. my issue was very specific rather than that general query.

Comment: @AlanBirtles i just checked these binaries are compiled with msvs compiler. i guess i should build it from source then. thanks.

Comment: or just use visual studio, it'll make your life easier in general than using mingw